# Error message while web scraping with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

i am trying to web scrape a internet site [Text](https://www.quantalys.com/Recherche)

I saw that in the bottom of the internet site the length of the data [[image: Image here]] which is 67,743 funds.
I have written a program to get this 67,743 fund information but when I change the length to 40_000 I get my data but when I type 67,743 I have an error message.
Is there anyone who has an idea ?

The error message is:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

data = {'columns[0][name]': 'ID_Produit',
                'columns[1][name]': 'cTypeFinancialItem',
                'columns[2][name]': 'cClasseFinancialItem',
                'columns[3][name]': 'sTypeFinancialObject',
                'columns[4][name]': 'checkbox',
                'columns[5][name]': 'sNom',
                'columns[6][name]': 'sURL',
                'columns[7][name]': 'sNomManager',
                'columns[8][name]': 'sNomTypeFinancialObject',
                'columns[9][name]': 'sGroupeCat_Specific_Dynamic',
                'columns[10][name]': 'sGroupeCat_rng1',
                'columns[11][name]': 'sCodeISIN',
                'columns[12][name]': 'nVL',
                'columns[13][name]': 'sCurrency',
                'columns[14][name]': 'nStarRating',
                'columns[15][name]': 'nScore',
                'columns[16][name]': 'nRetYTD',
                'columns[17][name]': 'nRet1a',
                'columns[18][name]': 'nRet3a',
                'columns[19][name]': 'nRet5a',
                'columns[20][name]': 'nRet1c',
                'columns[21][name]': 'nRet3c',
                'columns[22][name]': 'nRet1j',
                'columns[23][name]': 'nRet1m',
                'columns[24][name]': 'nRet3m',
                'columns[25][name]': 'nRet6m',
                'columns[26][name]': 'nRet5c',
                'columns[27][name]': 'nRet8c',
                'columns[28][name]': 'nVolat1a',
                'columns[29][name]': 'nVolat3a',
                'columns[30][name]': 'nVolat5a',
                'columns[31][name]': 'nSharpe1a',
                'columns[32][name]': 'nSharpe3a',
                'columns[33][name]': 'nSharpe5a',
                'columns[34][name]': 'nPerteMax1a',
                'columns[35][name]': 'nPerteMax3a',
                'columns[36][name]': 'nPerteMax5a',
                'columns[37][name]': 'nSortino1a',
                'columns[38][name]': 'nSortino3a',
                'columns[39][name]': 'nSortino5a',
                'columns[40][name]': 'nIr1A',
                'columns[41][name]': 'nIr3A',
                'columns[42][name]': 'nIr5A',
                'columns[43][name]': 'nMinInvest',
                'columns[44][name]': 'nFraisGestion',
                'columns[45][name]': 'nFraisEntree',
                'columns[46][name]': 'nFraisSortie',
                'columns[47][name]': 'dtRet',
                'columns[48][name]': 'dtRetMonth',
                'columns[49][name]': 'bFerme',
                'columns[50][name]': 'nIntensiteESG',
                'columns[51][name]': 'nActifEur',
                'columns[52][name]': 'nActifDiffEUR1m',
                'columns[53][name]': 'nActifDiffEUR3m',
                'columns[54][name]': 'nActifDiffEUR6m',
                'columns[55][name]': 'nActifDiffEUR1A',
                'columns[56][name]': 'nActifCompartimentEUR',
                'columns[57][name]': 'nActifCompartimentDiffEUR1m',
                'columns[58][name]': 'nActifCompartimentDiffEUR3m',
                'columns[59][name]': 'nActifCompartimentDiffEUR6m',
                'columns[60][name]': 'nActifCompartimentDiffEUR1A',
                'columns[61][name]': 'nCollecteCompartiment1m',
                'columns[62][name]': 'nCollecteCompartiment3m',
                'columns[63][name]': 'nCollecteCompartiment6m',
                'columns[64][name]': 'nCollecteCompartimentYTD',
                'columns[65][name]': 'nCollecteCompartiment1A',
                'columns[66][name]': 'nCollecteCompartiment3A',
                'columns[67][name]': 'nCollecteRet1m',
                'columns[68][name]': 'nCollecteRet3m',
                'columns[69][name]': 'nCollecteRet6m',
                'columns[70][name]': 'nCollecteRetYTD',
                'columns[71][name]': 'nCollecteRet1A',
                'columns[72][name]': 'nCollecteRet3A',
                'columns[73][name]': 'nCollecteCompartimentRet1m',
                'columns[74][name]': 'nCollecteCompartimentRet3m',
                'columns[75][name]': 'nCollecteCompartimentRet6m',
                'columns[76][name]': 'nCollecteCompartimentRetYTD',
                'columns[77][name]': 'nCollecteCompartimentRet1A',
                'columns[78][name]': 'nCollecteCompartimentRet3A',
                'columns[79][name]': 'isESG',
                'columns[80][name]': 'sArticleSFDR',
                'columns[81][name]': 'nIntensiteISR',
                'columns[82][name]': 'nESG_Environnement',
                'columns[83][name]': 'nESG_Social',
                'columns[84][name]': 'nESG_Gouvernance',
                'order[0][column]': '5',
                'order[0][dir]': 'asc',
                'start': '0',
                'length': '60741'
                }

response = requests.post('https://www.quantalys.com/Recherche/Data', headers=headers, data=data)
df_list_fonds = pd.DataFrame(response.json()['data'])
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: The code is inside my message !

Comment: Probably the limit of the response is that much, and if you're requesting more than the limit, website might be blocking you, as it isn't good a website to have loose endpoints from where all of the data can be scraped at once.

Comment: ok. But how can I know the limit ?

Comment: Hit and trial, and as per your details limit is `40_000`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `start` parameter in your data and load the data in chunk of, for example, 100:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

data = {'columns[0][name]': 'ID_Produit',
                'columns[1][name]': 'cTypeFinancialItem',
                'columns[2][name]': 'cClasseFinancialItem',
                'columns[3][name]': 'sTypeFinancialObject',
                'columns[4][name]': 'checkbox',
                'columns[5][name]': 'sNom',
                'columns[6][name]': 'sURL',
                'columns[7][name]': 'sNomManager',
                'columns[8][name]': 'sNomTypeFinancialObject',
                'columns[9][name]': 'sGroupeCat_Specific_Dynamic',
                'columns[10][name]': 'sGroupeCat_rng1',
                'columns[11][name]': 'sCodeISIN',
                'columns[12][name]': 'nVL',
                'columns[13][name]': 'sCurrency',
                'columns[14][name]': 'nStarRating',
                'columns[15][name]': 'nScore',
                'columns[16][name]': 'nRetYTD',
                'columns[17][name]': 'nRet1a',
                'columns[18][name]': 'nRet3a',
                'columns[19][name]': 'nRet5a',
                'columns[20][name]': 'nRet1c',
                'columns[21][name]': 'nRet3c',
                'columns[22][name]': 'nRet1j',
                'columns[23][name]': 'nRet1m',
                'columns[24][name]': 'nRet3m',
                'columns[25][name]': 'nRet6m',
                'columns[26][name]': 'nRet5c',
                'columns[27][name]': 'nRet8c',
                'columns[28][name]': 'nVolat1a',
                'columns[29][name]': 'nVolat3a',
                'columns[30][name]': 'nVolat5a',
                'columns[31][name]': 'nSharpe1a',
                'columns[32][name]': 'nSharpe3a',
                'columns[33][name]': 'nSharpe5a',
                'columns[34][name]': 'nPerteMax1a',
                'columns[35][name]': 'nPerteMax3a',
                'columns[36][name]': 'nPerteMax5a',
                'columns[37][name]': 'nSortino1a',
                'columns[38][name]': 'nSortino3a',
                'columns[39][name]': 'nSortino5a',
                'columns[40][name]': 'nIr1A',
                'columns[41][name]': 'nIr3A',
                'columns[42][name]': 'nIr5A',
                'columns[43][name]': 'nMinInvest',
                'columns[44][name]': 'nFraisGestion',
                'columns[45][name]': 'nFraisEntree',
                'columns[46][name]': 'nFraisSortie',
                'columns[47][name]': 'dtRet',
                'columns[48][name]': 'dtRetMonth',
                'columns[49][name]': 'bFerme',
                'columns[50][name]': 'nIntensiteESG',
                'columns[51][name]': 'nActifEur',
                'columns[52][name]': 'nActifDiffEUR1m',
                'columns[53][name]': 'nActifDiffEUR3m',
                'columns[54][name]': 'nActifDiffEUR6m',
                'columns[55][name]': 'nActifDiffEUR1A',
                'columns[56][name]': 'nActifCompartimentEUR',
                'columns[57][name]': 'nActifCompartimentDiffEUR1m',
                'columns[58][name]': 'nActifCompartimentDiffEUR3m',
                'columns[59][name]': 'nActifCompartimentDiffEUR6m',
                'columns[60][name]': 'nActifCompartimentDiffEUR1A',
                'columns[61][name]': 'nCollecteCompartiment1m',
                'columns[62][name]': 'nCollecteCompartiment3m',
                'columns[63][name]': 'nCollecteCompartiment6m',
                'columns[64][name]': 'nCollecteCompartimentYTD',
                'columns[65][name]': 'nCollecteCompartiment1A',
                'columns[66][name]': 'nCollecteCompartiment3A',
                'columns[67][name]': 'nCollecteRet1m',
                'columns[68][name]': 'nCollecteRet3m',
                'columns[69][name]': 'nCollecteRet6m',
                'columns[70][name]': 'nCollecteRetYTD',
                'columns[71][name]': 'nCollecteRet1A',
                'columns[72][name]': 'nCollecteRet3A',
                'columns[73][name]': 'nCollecteCompartimentRet1m',
                'columns[74][name]': 'nCollecteCompartimentRet3m',
                'columns[75][name]': 'nCollecteCompartimentRet6m',
                'columns[76][name]': 'nCollecteCompartimentRetYTD',
                'columns[77][name]': 'nCollecteCompartimentRet1A',
                'columns[78][name]': 'nCollecteCompartimentRet3A',
                'columns[79][name]': 'isESG',
                'columns[80][name]': 'sArticleSFDR',
                'columns[81][name]': 'nIntensiteISR',
                'columns[82][name]': 'nESG_Environnement',
                'columns[83][name]': 'nESG_Social',
                'columns[84][name]': 'nESG_Gouvernance',
                'order[0][column]': '5',
                'order[0][dir]': 'asc',
                'start': '0',
                'length': '100'
                }


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

all_data = []
for data['start'] in range(0, 67_744, 100):  # <-- this will go from 0 to 67700 in step of 100
    print(data['start'])
    all_data.extend(response.json()['data'])
    response = requests.post('https://www.quantalys.com/Recherche/Data', headers=headers, data=data)


df_list_fonds = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df_list_fonds)
```

Comment: your code is not working !

Comment: for data['start'] in range(0, 67_744, 100):  # <-- this will go from 0 to 67700 in step of 100     response = requests.post('https://www.quantalys.com/Recherche/Data', headers=headers, data=data)

    print(data['start'])
    all_data.extend(response.json()['data'])

Comment: because you invert the all_data.extend... line with response=... As I sent in my previous code. Thx

Comment: @jacques Sorry I don't understand. What do you mean by "invert"?

Comment: I mean the correct code is: for data['start'] in range(0, 67_744, 100): 
    response = requests.post('https://www.quantalys.com/Recherche/Data', headers=headers, data=data)     all_data.extend(response.json()['data'])

Comment: @jacques Ah, I see. Sorry for the typo :) the lines should be swapped. I'll edit it when StackOverflow let me.